# GN&C free / open source softwares suggestions

Tags: spacecraft, attitude, simulation

I am looking for a GN&C software free (and open source if possible) capable to compute the attitude and control including hardware profiles, example: RWs (reaction wheels) profiles

I know 42 does something, however it is not well documented (in this case if someone has some code to share, I will be very grateful...), however I was looking for some other opportunities.

Thank you in advance,

PDM

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Thanks for replying. I want to simulate attitude and control of the spacecraft including the hardware (for example reaction wheels) used for the actuation. Software like GMAT just allow to simulate attitude but not provide a detailed control and hardware modelisation

Answer (score 8):

[Basilisk](https://hanspeterschaub.info/basilisk/) by the AVS Lab at CU Boulder is an excellent 6-DOF framework for GNC. It has flown on several missions including the Emirati Mars Mission (EMM / [Al-Amal](https://space.skyrocket.de/doc_sdat/al-amal.htm)) and was planned to run the Masten Space System XL1 lunar lander as per a paper by their GNC team.

It is thoroughly validated, [open source](https://bitbucket.org/avslab/basilisk), and updated weekly.

Comment: Thanks for answering. We have tested Basilisk, and unfortunately we found many small bugs...  Do you know where to find more documentation and especially examples about 42 NASA tool?

Comment: @PietroDeMarchi, that may be: my team hadn't encountered any of significance when we were using on the XL-1 lunar lander. For having worked with three 6DOF, including BSK, I think it's truly excellent. First, it's tested (most 6DOFs are not). Second, if you find a bug, you can fix it and open a pull request so that everyone benefits from the fix. Third, there's excellent support on the forums. More generally, if it doesn't match a previous 6DOF, note that BSK has high fidelity models for the reaction wheel coupling than any simulation software out there (cf. John Alcorn's work in BSK).

Comment: Thank you a lot for your time and comments. We have opened the issue about J2 propagation divergence, and seen that other doubts have grown about using it. However I perfectly agree it really detailed and exhaustively describe many hardware components. So you use just that and any other open-source/free tools, isnt it?

Comment: @PietroDeMarchi, for 6DOF, yes, I use Basilisk. For 3DOF, I use Nyx (https://nyxspace.com/) or GMAT if I need something that Nyx doesn't yet have. At work, I often use AGI STK, but it really seems like Astrogator was an after thought of STK (and it's tens of thousands of dollars per year).